# A fire burnt my Leylandii hedge, what should I do?

Tags: hedge, leylandii

We just moved to a new house. The which previous owner used to take good care of his garden. A few days ago I was pruning the hedge and which I believe is a Leyland Cypress. I found some brown patches and now I am worried. ( will take some pix later and update this post).

A fire destroyed a good portion of it, and regarding this I have 2 questions:

Should I cut off the burnt branches to help regrowth or can I leave it as it is?
How long will it take to grow again?

Thanks very much in advance.

Burnt area
[image: burnt hedge]

Comment: Leylandii grows fast, so replanting would also be an option. Leylandii wouldn't be my first choice though (grows fast = maintenance) and little grows underneath it (not a problem where your path is)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @winwaed has pointed out the Leyland cypress grows fast. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leyland_Cypress) describes it as

> The plant's rapid growth (up to a metre per year) and great potential
>   height (often over 20 metres (66 ft) tall, sometimes as high as 35
>   metres (115 ft)) can become a serious problem.

If you wait it should regrow but might be a little distorted as the main stems have been damaged. For this approach cut back the growth until you get to live tissue. If you replant you will end with a more uniform appearance but you have to wait for it to get to a height that gives privacy.

If this were my choice I would build a fence.  Instant privacy with less maintenance.

Comment: But fences often have height restrictions.